Nodejs how to get cpu usage in percentage?
So guys heres my code:
import os from "os";
import process from "process";

export const getCpuInfo = () => {
    const cpuUsage = process.cpuUsage();
    const totalCpuUsage = cpuUsage.user + cpuUsage.system;
    const numCPUs = os.cpus().length;
  
    // Calculate the total CPU time in seconds
    const totalCpuTime = process.uptime();
  
    // Calculate the CPU usage percentage
    const cpuUsagePercentage = (totalCpuUsage / (totalCpuTime * 1e6)) * 100;
  
  let modelName;
  let modelSpeed;
  let displayed = false;
  os.cpus().forEach(cpu => {
    if (displayed) return;
    modelName = cpu.model;
    modelSpeed = cpu.speed;
    return displayed = true;
  })

  return {
    cpuSpeed: formatHertz(modelSpeed),
    cpuModel: modelName,
    cpuCores: numCPUs,
    cpuParallelism: os.availableParallelism(),
    cpuUsage: cpuUsagePercentage.toFixed(2) // Format as a percentage with 2 decimal places
  }
}

function formatHertz(megaHertz) {
  try {
    let hertz = Number(megaHertz);
    let Ghz = hertz / 1000;
    return `${Ghz.toFixed(2)} Ghz`; // Round to 2 decimal places
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
}

function convertNumberFormat(number) {
    const megahertz = number / 1e6; // Convert to megahertz
    return megahertz.toFixed(2); // Return with 2 decimal places
  }

But I am actually not able to get the cpu usage percentage
I tried using third party-libraraies but they didn't worked as I wanted.
I want the cpu usage percentage to get displayed in the format like: 22.23%
Can anyone help me with above code?
I am using windows btw
Thanks in advance

Do you need CPU load average? If you are on Linux you can do a system call to execute uptime, then extract the average load for 1 min, 5 min and 15 min. Example: const { exec } = require('child_process'); exec('uptime', (err, stdout, stderr) => { console.log('uptime: ' + stdout); });

I am in windows

Here how you can get cpu percentage in express:
`const os = require("os");

// Function to get CPU info
const getCPUInfo = () => {
  const cpus = os.cpus();
  let totalIdle = 0,
    totalTick = 0;

  cpus.forEach((core) => {
    for (type in core.times) {
      totalTick += core.times[type];
    }
    totalIdle += core.times.idle;
  });

  return { idle: totalIdle, total: totalTick };
};

// Function to calculate CPU percentage
const calculateCPUUsage = (start, end) => {
  const idleDifference = end.idle - start.idle;
  const totalDifference = end.total - start.total;

  const percentageCPU =
    100 - Math.floor((100 * idleDifference) / totalDifference);

  return percentageCPU;
};

// Initial CPU information
let startMeasure = getCPUInfo();

// Function to get CPU percentage at intervals
const getCPUPercentage = () => {
  const endMeasure = getCPUInfo();
  const cpuPercent = calculateCPUUsage(startMeasure, endMeasure);

  startMeasure = endMeasure; // Update startMeasure for the next interval

  return cpuPercent;
};

// Example Express.js route to return CPU usage
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/cpu-usage", (req, res) => {
  const cpuPercentage = getCPUPercentage();
  res.json({ cpuUsage: `${cpuPercentage}%` });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});


Nah it's working fine, I am using Node version 20+ so it's available, btw do you know hot calculate the CPU usage and display it in percentage?

Yes you can calculate cpu percentage using os module

Alright can you show me?
